# How to move JFrames on other screens?

Tags: java, jframe

I've created a programme, which opens 4 Jframes containing applets.
I would like to move these Frames from my Main-Screen to my second, but it's not working.

I've tried with the `.setLocation(x,y)`-method, but it the jframes still won't move over the edge of the screen.

I even tried with getting the bound with the `graphicsdevice.getdefaultconfiguration.getBounds()`, but the result is "0", so it opens the JFrames on 0,0 on my main screen every time.

Hope, anyone understands my problem and can help me :D

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english :S

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your 2-monitor setup, left or right of the center screen, you can just use negative value for x to move it to the left monitor, or a value larger than the width of the center monitor to move it to the right monitor.

Beware: If you have different height of the monitors make sure the y-value is within the bounds of it too.

For example if you have a  monitor to the left of the center screen:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Hello world"));
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
f.setLocation(0, 200);

JFrame f2 = new JFrame();
f2.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Hello world 2"));
f2.pack();
f2.setVisible(true);
f2.setLocation(-400, 500);
```

Monitors vertically stacked left as an exercisefor the dev. :)

Of course if you don't want to hard code those values there is a way to find the different screen sizes and offsets in x and y (if not the same size for example):

```
    GraphicsDevice[] gds = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
    for (GraphicsDevice gd : gds) {
        for(GraphicsConfiguration gc : gd.getConfigurations()) {
            Rectangle bounds = gc.getBounds();
            System.out.println("x,y: "+bounds.getX() + "," + bounds.getY() + " width,height: " + bounds.getWidth() + "x" + bounds.getHeight());
        }
    }
```

For me right now, having two screens, with one big screen 27" center and one 24" to the left:

```
x,y: 0.0,0.0 width,height: 2560.0x1440.0
x,y: -1920.0,232.0 width,height: 1920.0x1200.0
```

Explanation:
The left screen's left side is at `x=-1920`

Comment: Yes the first method is the same i already have done but it does not work for me. for example my screens are 1280*1080, i write .setLocation(1281,0). But the frame appears then on the first Screen at (1,0)?!

Comment: the second method with graphicdevice i already tried, too. but everytime the value from .getConfigurations is 0?

Comment: What's your exact screen setup? Which one is the primary and is the other to the right or left? Meaning should you use a negative number or a positive. Are the screens mirrored and not two separate logic screens then? Are you printing for all screendevices and all configurations? Could you give us the entire output from running the above screendevice configuration code above?